# It seems kids can resolve this puzzle faster than developers

Tags: pattern

> It seems kids can resolve this puzzle faster than developers

So, can you solve this puzzle ?

---

| 8809 = 6 | 5555 = 0 | 7111 = 0 |

| 8193 = 3 | 2172 = 0 | 8096 = 5 |

| 6666 = 4 | 1012 = 1 | 1111 = 0 |

| 7777 = 0 | 3213 = 0 | 9999 = 4 |

| 7662 = 2 | 7756 = 1 | 9313 = 1 |

| 6855 = 3 | 0000 = 4 | 9881 = 5 |

| 2222 = 0 | 5331 = 0 | 3333 = 0 |

---

> What is the answer to 2581 = ?

I do not have any merit on this one since I didn't create it.
I just found it sympathic to share. Have fun !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> 2

Explanation:

> The result is the number of "holes" in the digits that form each number.